# CLI command for Sonarqube Upgrade browser step

Tags: automation, sonarqube, upgrade

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

I am just going through this documentation to upgrade Sonarqube.
One of the steps is to open the URL in browser and follow instructions.

Is there any CLI command available for this step? So that I can automate this step in my upgrade automation?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to automate something you do at most once every 2 months?

Comment: we have couple of sonar servers, and we have dev, test, prod.. mostly we upgrade test & prod in the weekends.. so mostly, every sprint we do one upgrade.. we are just trying to minimize the number of step executions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (or even all?) UI interactions only trigger Web API calls.

In your case, [`api/system/migrate_db`](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/system/migrate_db) seems to serve your purpose.

From the api documentation:

> Migrate the database to match the current version of SonarQube.
>   Sending a POST request to this URL starts the DB migration. It is
>   strongly advised to make a database backup before invoking this WS.

To call it from the command line use:

```
curl -s -u admin:admin -XPOST "localhost:9000/api/system/migrate_db"
```

- `curl` is a linux command line tool for to communicate via HTTP
- `-s` toggle "silent mode"
- `-u admin:admin` provides authentication
- `-XPOST` set's the HTTP method to `POST` (instead of default `GET`)